# Trabalhando com hora no pandas e python

Tags: python, linux, pandas

Tenho um `dataFrame` no qual duas colunas são do tipo `datetime.time` e eu preciso subtrair uma da outra e obter o valor em minutos.

Para transformar em `datetime.time` fiz assim:

```
gcr['hora_inicio_atividade'] = pd.to_datetime(gcr['hora_inicio_atividade'],format= '%H:%M:%S').dt.time

gcr['data_saida'] = pd.to_datetime(gcr['data_saida'],format= '%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Quando eu vou criar um novo campo com subtração dos dois acima o interpretador acusa o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and
>   'datetime.time'

Answer (score 4):

Não existe diferença entre horários. Não faz sentido.

Se eu te pedir qual é a diferença entre 11:00:00 e 10:00:00 você até pode ficar atentado a responder que é 1 hora, mas está errado, pois o horário 11:00:00 é do dia 25/12/2025, enquanto o horário 10:00:00 é do dia 01/03/1993. O intervalo entre esses dois instantes é muito maior que apenas 1 hora.

Porém, percebeu que somente pelo fato de eu citar também a data começou a fazer sentido analisar o intervalo de tempo? Pois é, analisar o intervalo entre instantes de tempo de datas definidas é perfeitamente plausível. Isto é, ao invés de subtrair objetos do tipo `datetime.time`, subtraia `datetime.datetime`.

```
from datetime import datetime

final = datetime.strptime('11:45:13', '%H:%M:%S')
inicial = datetime.strptime('10:30:07', '%H:%M:%S')

intervalo = final - inicial

print(intervalo)  # 1:15:06
```

**Mas cade a data?**

Por padrão, o módulo `datetime` utilizará a data 1900-01-01 como referência e, se você não informar explicitamente, será essa data que será considerada. Assim, no exemplo, você estaria analisando o intervalo entre 1900-01-01 11:45:13 e 1900-01-01 10:30:07. Como são horários do mesmo dia, não importa muito se a data está correta ou não, mas caso precise de datas diferentes você precisará informar explicitamente.