# Informar dois totais de horas diferentes e ter como saída a quantidade de horas entre as duas informadas

Tags: python-3.x, string, conversão-de-tipo, condição

**Nesse problema não posso utilizar nenhuma lib pronta!!!!!**

Então, em Python 3, devo fazer o que se pede, porém, estou apresentando dificuldades para implementar isso, até então tentei calcular as diferenças dos dois horários(que estão no formato HH:MM:SS) convertendo cada trecho(horas e min.) em segundos, mas há outras condições que não consigo encontrar.
exemplos de entrada:

> 1)23:59:59
>
> 02:40:00
>
> 2)21:10:00
>
> 21:07:01
>
> saída
>
> 1)02:40:01
>
> 2)23:57:01

No momento, consegui tirar a diferença, mas tive problemas na saída

```
time1 = (input())
time2 = (input())

hora1 = time1[0]+time1[1]
minuto1 = time1[3]+time1[4]
segundo1 = time1[6]+time1[7]

horareal1 = int(hora1)
minutoreal1 = int(minuto1)
segundoreal1 = int(segundo1)

hora2 = time2[0]+time2[1]
minuto2 = time2[3]+time2[4]
segundo2 = time2[6]+time2[7]

horareal2 = int(hora2)
minutoreal2 = int(minuto2)
segundoreal2 = int(segundo2)

if horareal1 > 23 or minutoreal1 > 59 or segundoreal1 > 59 or horareal2 > 23 or minutoreal2 > 59 or segundoreal2 > 59:
    exit()


if hora1 >= hora2:
    #p/hora1
    x = minutoreal1*60
    y = horareal1*3600
    z = x+y+segundoreal1

    #p/hora2
    x1 = minutoreal2*60
    y1 = horareal2*3600
    z1 = x1+y1+segundoreal2
    #subtraíndo p/hora

    segtotal = z-z1
    x2 = int(segtotal/3600)
    x22 = x2*3600
    #subtraído os segundos totais
    segtotal2 = segtotal-x22
    #subtraíndo p/minuto
    y2 = int(segtotal2/60)
    y22 = y2*60
    segtotal3 = segtotal2-y22


    print(x2,':',y2,':',segtotal3)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Trabalhando com hora no pandas e python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355039/trabalhando-com-hora-no-pandas-e-python)

Comment: Se o projeto é importante, por que não pode utilizar pacotes que já fazem o trabalho para você?

Comment: Limitação dada pela professora, sem libs, infelizmente

Comment: Então, por favor, edite a pergunta e detalhe o que você já conseguiu fazer e quais as dificuldades encontradas no processo.

Comment: Okay, obrigado, farei isso